# Cannot change brightness on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dell, laptop, brightness, xps

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and suddenly I'm not able to change the display brightness through any GUI tool, either in settings or via power indicator.

- The setting is active, aka I can see the slider
- I can move it right/left but this does not change the brightness
- When I close the window and open again the value is back to the value before I changed anything
- There is also setting for the keyboard backlight in there which works OK

Everything worked just 2 days ago and suddenly stopped, there weren't any updates installed in between, the only thing that could remotely affect this which I did is playing with the `chown -R` around Python packages as my user did not have rights to run half of them.

I tried bunch of solutions I found online, changing GRUB options, adding new files to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`, no changes. I

The only way that I found that works is to set the value manually in `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

My laptop is Dell XPS 9570, kernel `4.15.0-46-generic`.

Any ideas how to debug further?